# Force the HTML tag to be inactive

Tags: html

I'm working on a project and want to give a guide to my visitors like this :

> Use < b >text< / b > to make **text**

How to write it? (Of course without spaces in < b > tag)

Without CSS will be better

Thanks in advance

Comment: Take a look at this [HTML entities reference chart](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref). For example, `&gt;` will output `>` in HTML. Similarly, `&lt;` will output `<`. You'd be looking for something like `&lt;b&gt;` for `<b>`.

Comment: @Fizik26 If you think the question is a duplicate, why not mark it as such? Or maybe it's a rep thing, in which case, no worries :)

Comment: Oh I didn't know that I can mark it like a duplicate. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
Use &lt;b&gt;text&lt;/b&gt; to make <b>text</b>
```

You have to use HTML Escape / Unescape.

1. " is replaced with "
2. & is replaced with &
3. < is replaced with <
4. > is replaced with >

Comment: OP is asking how to print `<b>text</b>` *literally* on their page, not trying to make text bold.

Comment: Ok but I change my answer, better now?

Comment: The answer is better, but in general you shouldn't answer questions that are *clear* duplicates. It encourages people to ask questions that they could've found answers to with a simple search.

Comment: Thanks, I understand, but it is not the first time it happens.